# simplexml gives Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in line 136 and when commented out line 156

Tags: php, xml, svg

with my code I am trying to grab the path data from a xml (used to be svg) file and while I am able to successfully print out the data by the $attributes array, using echo it still pulls up the "call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in (line 136 and 156)
I simply don't see what is wrong with the code, although worst case scenario I can always use a hack around that inserts the selected data into a db within the while loop and upon iteration forward to the desired page... I am wondering what exactly is wrong with my code. 
it echos out the correct information with the echo commands. it just still gives the call to a member function on a non object error

```
while($number_of_array_path >=1)
{
//declares attributes based on path number for sodipodi attributes line136
$attributes = $xml_file_open->g->path[$path_incremental_counter]-
>attributes('sodipodi', true); 

//sets each attribute within an array and uses the path incremental counter for 
//that pourpose.
$type_array[$path_incremental_counter] = $attributes['type'];
$cx_array[$path_incremental_counter] = $attributes['cx'];
$cy_array[$path_incremental_counter] = $attributes['cy'];
$rx_array[$path_incremental_counter] = $attributes['rx'];
$ry_array[$path_incremental_counter] = $attributes['ry'];
echo $type_array[$path_incremental_counter];
echo "<br/>";                               
echo $cx_array[$path_incremental_counter];
echo "<br/>";                               
echo $cy_array[$path_incremental_counter];
echo "<br/>";
echo $rx_array[$path_incremental_counter];
echo "<br/>";
echo $ry_array[$path_incremental_counter];
echo "<br/>";                               


//same as above but for non"sodipodi" attributes. line 156
$attributes = $xml_file_open->g->path[$path_incremental_counter]->attributes();
// echo $attributes['id'];  
$style_array[$path_incremental_counter] = $attributes['style'];
$id_array[$path_incremental_counter] = $attributes['id'];
$d_array[$path_incremental_counter] = $attributes['d'];
echo $style_array[$path_incremental_counter];
echo "<br/>";
echo $id_array[$path_incremental_counter];
echo "<br/>";
echo $d_array[$path_incremental_counter];
echo "<br/>";



//increments path incremental counter
$path_incremental_counter = $path_incremental_counter + 1;
//decrements number of array path
$number_of_array_path = $number_of_array_path;                                                              
}
```

Comment: Is `$path_incremental_counter` initialized to 0, or is it NULl on the first pass? Did you `var_dump($xml_file_open->g->path)`

Comment: $path_incremental_counter is initialized to 0, I did not var_dump($xml_file_open->g->path)

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(5) { ["type"]=> string(3) "arc" ["cx"]=> string(9) "417.14285" ["cy"]=> string(9) "420.93362" ["rx"]=> string(9) "165.71428" ["ry"]=> string(9) "91.428574" } } fill:#ff0000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1 is the result I get, I assume the style atribute (item with fill(svg)) is where the error is. now since I can't control how the style is output, what can I do to change it so it accepts the style output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($xml_file_open->g->path[$shape_path_iteration_counter]->attributes() 
as $attribute => $value)
```

for non sodipodi elements

```
foreach($xml_file_open->g->path[$shape_path_iteration_counter]->
attributes('sodipodi', true) as $attribute => $value)
```

for sodipodi elements.